# this selector issue with ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

```
 $(".selectedBatch").each(function(index){

      var batchCode = $(this).text();

      //edit batch attr start 

      $.ajax({

          url: "../Controller/getBatchAttr.php",
          type: "GET",
          async: false, 
          data: "BM_Course_Code="+ batchCode,
          success:function(resBatch){
              console.log($(this).text());
              //$(this).attr("data-commence-date",resBatch.BM_Commence_Date);
              //$(this).attr("data-end-date",resBatch.BM_End_Date);
              //$(this).attr("data-ins-days",resBatch.BM_Ins_Days);
          }
      });
      //edit batch attr end 
  });
```

Why does `console.log($(this).text());` return an empty output inside success function?

Comment: did you mean to use console.log(batchCode)?

Comment: no.Inside the success function

Comment: Not sure what this refers to inside success function. try console.log($(this)) and see you got the object you intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` is not a local variable, so it's not saved in closures. You need to set a local variable to it, and use that instead:

```
$(".selectedBatch").each(function(index){

    var $that = $(this);
    var batchCode = $that.text();

    //edit batch attr start 

    $.ajax({

        url: "../Controller/getBatchAttr.php",
        type: "GET",
        async: false, 
        data: {BM_Course_Code: batchCode},
        success:function(resBatch){
            console.log($that.text());
            //$that.data("commence-date",resBatch.BM_Commence_Date);
            //$that.data("end-date",resBatch.BM_End_Date);
            //$that.data("ins-days",resBatch.BM_Ins_Days);
        }
    });
    //edit batch attr end 
});
```

Other changes I've made:

- Pass an object as the `data:` option. jQuery will ensure that it's properly URL-encoded (you forgot to call `encodeURIComponent`).
- Instead of `.attr("data-XXX", ...)` I use `.data("XXX", ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the success function this refers to ajax object getting created when you call $.ajax. You have already created variable for the text. You can use that instead of using $(this).text()

```
$(".selectedBatch").each(function(index){

      var batchCode = $(this).text();

      //edit batch attr start 

      $.ajax({

          url: "../Controller/getBatchAttr.php",
          type: "GET",
          async: false, 
          data: "BM_Course_Code="+ batchCode,
          success:function(resBatch){
              console.log(batchCode );
              //$(this).attr("data-commence-date",resBatch.BM_Commence_Date);
              //$(this).attr("data-end-date",resBatch.BM_End_Date);
              //$(this).attr("data-ins-days",resBatch.BM_Ins_Days);
          }
      });
      //edit batch attr end 
  });
```

Comment: I think the `console.log()` is just for debugging, and in his real application he cares about the `.attr()` lines that are commented out.

Comment: @Barmar yes.I want to fill those commend out things.I was tested it with console.log.Now i know about the this selector mucm more.Thanks

Comment: @samitha It would have been clearer if you hadn't commented them out. How was vishwanath to know that commented lines are important.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `context` object here like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "../Controller/getBatchAttr.php",
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    data: "BM_Course_Code=" + batchCode,
    context: this,    // <--- using context as `this` here
    success: function (resBatch) {
        console.log($(this).text());   // Now you can use `this` here
    }
});
```

This `context` object will be made the context of all Ajax-related callbacks.